# Symfony2 SecurityIdentity and ACE remove

Tags: php, symfony, acl

I create a new RoleSecurityIdentity and ROLE if a new UserGroup is generated. Like:

```
new RoleSecurityIdentity('ROLE_GROUP-'.$groupName);
```

If the Admin creates a new Object, like a Media, he can assign the Groups to the Media to View:

```
$acl->insertObjectAce($groupSecurityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_VIEW);
```

Now i have the Problem, that i don´t know how to revoke all the Aces of the RoleSecurityIdentity if i remove a Group?

Are there any ready Functions etc.? Didn´t found some yet, so i coded this:

```
 $connection = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection();
 // find securityIdentity ID
 $secIdSearch = $connection->prepare('select * from acl_security_identities where identifier = "'.$groupRole.'"');
 $secIdSearch->execute();
 $secIdFetch = $secIdSearch->fetch();
 $securityIdentitiyId = $secIdFetch['id'];

 if($securityIdentitiyId):
      // Delete all connected Object Entities for this RoleIdentitiys
  $connection->prepare('DELETE FROM acl_entries where security_identity_id ='.$securityIdentitiyId)->execute();
      // Remove the Role Identitiy itself. 
  $connection->prepare('DELETE FROM acl_security_identities where id ='.$securityIdentitiyId)->execute();
 endif;
```

It not only looks really dirty, if i want to save a new ACL on a Object i removed the Ace from, i get a

```
 Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in  /../../Acl/Dbal/MutableAclProvider.php line 842
```

because the ace_order isn´t correct.

Is there a solution already? 
Or i have to go my way and have to re order the aces?

Comment: I'm also having problems with the ace_order being out of sync, and was wondering if you came across any solution to your problem? - Thanks.

Comment: sadly, no. would be nice if you could inform me if you found one!

Answer (score 0):

test this :

```
public function myDeleteAce($securityIdentity, $acl,$entity){
    foreach($acl->getObjectAces() as $index => $ace) {

        if($securityIdentity->equals($ace->getSecurityIdentity())) {
                if (count($acl->getObjectAces())== 1){
                    $objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($entity);
                    $this->provider->deleteAcl($objectIdentity);
                    $response = ('No more ACE, So ACL deleted');
                }else{
                    $acl->deleteObjectAce($index);
                    $this->provider->updateAcl($acl);
                    $response = ('Rights deleted !');
                }



        }  



            }
    return $response;
}
```

I hope this can help you